# Analytic/Smooth/Continuous maps between a manifold and itself

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, topological-groups

Let us suppose that $M_{\omega}$ is a connected real-analytic manifold of dimension $n$. Then there is an associated smooth structure, $\mathcal{C}^r$ structure ($r$ non-negative integer) on it.
Let $G_{\omega}$ denote the group of analytic functions from $M_{\omega}$ to itself which have an analytic inverse. Let $G_{\infty}, G_{r}$ be defined similarly.

My questions are

> > 1.) What is known about the groups defined above ? (Anything about their structure, their interesting subgroups, or their homomorphic images etc.)

It appears to me that all the groups defined above are *very big* in general. For example in case $M=\mathbb{R}$, the group $G_{\omega}$ contains all maps of the type $x \to x+ \mu Sin (f(x))$ where $\mu$ is sufficiently small and $f(x)$ is analytic with bounded derivative. So it appears that this group is too big to be a finite dimensional Lie group.

> > 2.) Is there a natural way to give these groups a manifold structure so as to make them 'infinite dimensional Lie groups' ?
> >
> > 3.) Are there conditions on $M$ which would ensure that any of these groups is a finite dimensional Lie group ?

If I am not making a mistake, in case $M=\mathbb{R}^n$, the action of each of these groups on $M$ is $p$-transitive where $p$ is any positive integer.

> > 4.) Does it generalize to the general case where $M$ is not a Euclidean space ? Is the action of any of these groups 'infinity transitive' i.e. given two arbitrary sequences $\{ a_i\}$, $\{ b_i\}$ which have no limit point, does there exist an element of any of these groups which takes the sequence $\{ a_i\}$ to $\{ b_i\}$ ? Can we answer this question in specific cases (e.g. $M$ Euclidean) if not in general case ?
> >
> > 5.) One can look at the vector space of all real valued analytic/smooth/continuous functions defined on $M$. These vector spaces are also infinite dimensional in general. Is there a good description of the quotient of any of these vector spaces e.g. analytic functions modulo smooth functions ?

Please feel free to answer other natural related questions in these directions. It would be great if somebody could advise me some good references (books/articles/lecture notes) which addresses these or similar questions.

I had come across a book 'Continuous Groups of Transformations' by L.P.Eisenhart though am not sure what exactly it deals with and had asked a question about it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551753/continuous-groups-of-transformations-reference-request). Is this book a relevant reference for the kind of questions that I ask in this post ?

Some parts of this question are a bit vague, sorry about that.

Comment: Some of your questions are already discussed on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism#Diffeomorphism_group Eisenhart's book is unlikely to be about what you want: it is a more general treatise mostly on finite dimensional Lie groups. If you google "Diffeomorphism group" you will find a wealth of information.

Comment: In your question (5), presumably you mean "smooth functions modulo analytic functions". The other way doesn't make sense.

Comment: For question (2), Michor's article http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/mf-smo-2.pdf may be useful.

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks a lot ! And you are right, I meant  "smooth functions modulo analytic functions".